# Adding multiple columns with different formulas in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm trying to add in 3 columns to my dataframe that are formulas of existing columns.

First two additional columns provide a True or False outcome, but the third doesn't.

I'm not sure what is missing from the script that means the third column isn't working.

```
userId,Day 0,serviceDate,Call Count,Count Day,Count Days between Day 1 - Day 30,Count Days between Day 31 - Day 60,Count Days between Day 61 - 90
0,XXXXX,2019-02-21 00:00:00,2019-03-01 00:00:00,8,8,True,False,
1,XXXXX,2019-02-21 00:00:00,2019-03-08 00:00:00,8,15,True,False,
```

I have tried adding .loc as below but I haven't had any success yet.

```
call_count = Calls_withDay0.groupby('userID').count()[['serviceDate']]
call_count.rename(columns={'serviceDate': 'Call Count'}, inplace=True)

call_count.to_csv("call_count.csv")

call_added = Calls_withDay0.merge(call_count, how='left', left_on='userID', right_on='userID')

##add column with formula

call_added['Count Day'] = (call_added['serviceDate'] - call_added['Day 0']).dt.days
# count between day range - true or false


call_added.loc[:, 'Count Days between Day 1 - Day 30'] = ((call_added['Count Day'] > 0) & (call_added['Count Day'] <= 30))
call_added.loc[:, 'Count Days between Day 31 - Day 60'] = ((call_added['Count Day'] > 31) & (call_added['Count Day'] <= 60))
call_added.loc[:, 'Count Days between Day 61 - Day 90'] = ((call_added['Count Day'] > 61) & (call_added['Count Day'] <= 90))

print(call_added.head(3))
header4 = ['userID', 'Day 0', 'serviceDate', 'Call Count', 'Count Day', 'Count Days between Day 1 - Day 30',
           'Count Days between Day 31 - Day 60', 'Count Days between Day 61 - 90']

##save to csv
call_added.to_csv("calladded.csv", columns=header4)
```

I'm currently getting this error message:

> ```
> "FutureWarning: 
> Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
> KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
>
> See the documentation here:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
>   return self._getitem_tuple(key)"
> ```

But also more importantly I'm getting a completely empty 'Count Days between Day 61 - Day 90' column.

Comment: From the first snippet, it seems your column headers and values are not aligned.  To help you further, what is the output of `print(call_added.head(3))`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of print(call_added.columns) and print(call_added.head(3))

Index(['billableUnitId_x', 'channel_x', 'DNA_x', 'serviceDate',
       'numberOfMinutes_x', 'mode_x', 'status_x', 'type_x', 'patientId',
       'coachFirstName_x', 'coachLastName_x', 'profitCenterName_x',
       'contract_x', 'billableUnitId_y', 'channel_y', 'DNA_y', 'Day 0',
       'numberOfMinutes_y', 'mode_y', 'status_y', 'type_y', 'coachFirstName_y',
       'coachLastName_y', 'profitCenterName_y', 'contract_y', 'Call Count',
       'Count Day', 'Count Days between Day 1 - Day 30',
       'Count Days between Day 31 - Day 60',
       'Count Days between Day 61 - Day 90'],
      dtype='object')

billableUnitId_x  ... Count Days between Day 61 - Day 90
0            40295  ...                              False
1            41551  ...                              False
2            42743  ...                              False

[3 rows x 30 columns]